# Animate 2 elements on scroll at certain point [speed issue]

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to animate two different images once user reached the certain point on the page.
I did that actually, but the only problem is when you using trackpad, you can see the moving elements animation's very "slow" while it's fine when you using mouse to scroll the page.
I also tried to set the queue animation to false but that didn't help either.

Any help would be appreciated.

My code is below :

```
<div class="logo-cnt">
    <div class="logo-glyph">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=50%C3%9750&w=50&h=50">
    </div>
    <div class="logo-typeface">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=120%C3%9750&w=120&h=50">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="lq">

</div>
```

jQuery :

```
var position = $('.lq').offset().top;
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(y > position){
        $(".logo-typeface").stop().animate({right:50, opacity:0}, 100, "linear");
        $(".logo-glyph").stop().animate({left:63}, 100);  
    }else{
        $(".logo-typeface").stop().animate({right:0, opacity:1}, 100, "linear");
        $(".logo-glyph").stop().animate({left:0}, 100);       
      }
});
```

See the live version here [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mkvz6uwu/)

Comment: For those without trackpads -  the behavior exists when left clicking the scroll bar to scroll.

Comment: @DevinH.i just needed to be consistent on all experiences.

Comment: Yup, added that comment so those without trackpads can reproduce the issue so they can hopefully find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to me to be the browser blocking Javascript execution while a scroll is in action. So for a mouse since it scrolls at an interval (move 10 y every scroll position) it isn't noticeable. But for a trackpad, scrolling is at a much finer grain.

The solution I came up with is to use CSS animations instead of Javascript, as these don't get blocked.

http://jsfiddle.net/mkvz6uwu/1/

```
@keyframes logo-typeface-move-left {
    from {right: 0; opacity: 1;}
    to {right: 50px; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes logo-typeface-move-right {
    from {right: 50px; opacity: 0;}
    to {right: 0; opacity: 1;}
}

.logo-typeface-move-left {
    opacity: 0;
    right: 50px;
    animation-name: logo-typeface-move-left;
    animation-duration: .5s;
}

.logo-typeface-move-right {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
    animation-name: logo-typeface-move-right;
    animation-duration: .5s;
}

@keyframes logo-glyph-move-right {
    from {left: 0;}
    to {left: 63px;}
}

@keyframes logo-glyph-move-left {
    from {left: 63px;}
    to {left: 0;}
}

.logo-glyph-move-right {
    left: 63px;
    animation-name: logo-glyph-move-right;
    animation-duration: .5s;
}

.logo-glyph-move-left {
    left: 0;
    animation-name: logo-glyph-move-left;
    animation-duration: .5s;
}
```

And then add/remove classes with jQuery using same logic as before.

```
if (y > position) {
        $(".logo-typeface").removeClass('logo-typeface-move-right').addClass('logo-typeface-move-left');
        $(".logo-glyph").removeClass('logo-glyph-move-left').addClass('logo-glyph-move-right');
    } else {
        $(".logo-typeface").removeClass('logo-typeface-move-left').addClass('logo-typeface-move-right');
        $(".logo-glyph").removeClass('logo-glyph-move-right').addClass('logo-glyph-move-left');
    }
```